# Hack for connecting two terminal blocks?

Tags: dc, adapter, terminal, screw-terminal

If I bought some of these [connectors.](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B01MRZANEB/ref=ox_sc_act_title_1?smid=AGO4OAA9TSLP4&psc=1)

[image]

Is there an easy way to connect two of the green terminal blocks together? i.e. I would end up with a male to male DC adaptor.

Could I do this without having to use a cable that connects both of the green ends together?

Can I insert a double headed pin connector directly into a terminal block (you know the ones you get as part of universal charging kits).

Or does such a connector already exist?

Comment: Why are you asking this *after* having already bought the parts?

Comment: I know of no specially designed part. it's use steel wire (EG: paperclip, MIG WELING) if strength is most important or solid copper wire if electrical resistance is more important.

Comment: I did say *if* I bought these parts....

Comment: @jasen - I would never have considered a paperclip, but might be worth a go for curiosities sake

Comment: That would be "If I *buy* these parts ...*".

Comment: That is a fair point

Comment: what are you making?

Comment: I have a DC power supply with a female only output, so I figured if I could bodge two of the parts above together then I would have a method of making a universal male-to-male adaptor. And just to confirm - I have managed to buy these and bodge two of them together with a paperclip....it works great!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go find an electrician, and ask him (or her) for 6 inches of standard wiring cable for connecting junction boxes. Take this home and cut off the insulation. You'll have 3 six-inch lengths of solid 14 or 12 gauge wire. Stick one end of one piece into your terminal strip and measure the depth. Double this. Now cut two pieces of that length. Stick them into one terminal block and tighten. Now take the second block and rotate it 180 degrees so the screws are on the other side from the first, insert the wire, butt the two strips firmly together and tighten. Now wrap the blocks with 3 or 4 wraps of insulating tape (not scotch tape or masking tape) and you're done.

Note that if you butt the two blocks with the screws facing in the same direction you'll swap the inner and outer conductors of the cylindrical section.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using two short lengths of stiff wire.  Cut the wires just long enough so that the two parts abut with the wires sticking most of the way into the connectors.  It looks like maybe two ½ or ¾ inch pieces of #12 or #14 wire would do it and be stiff enough for the result to feel like one unit.  Add gobs of hot glue or epoxy and you're done.

Note that you need to flip the two connectors upside down from each other to connect outside to outside and center to center.